# Calling the constructor of an abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance

Say I have the following class structure:

```
public class A{
    A(int a){
        ...
    }
}

abstract class B extends A{

}

public class C extends B{
    C(int a){
        super(a);
    }
}
```

This code isn't valid in the sense that myMethod will not call A's constructor. Is there a way to do this?

What I ultimately want to do, is add functionality to a set of classes without affecting their functionality. All these classes currently extend a common class (runtimeException), so I was thinking of adding an intermediary abstract class.

(edit: the code in C shouldn't be a method, it was meant to be a constructor)

Comment: "add functionality to a set of classes without affecting their functionality" ?

Comment: You cannot call a constructor (`this(...)` or `super(...)`) from a method, only from another constructor. What *exactly* are you trying to do with `myMethod`? Perhaps `myMethod` should be a constructor instead of a method?

Comment: why does B has to be abstract? When you want to avoid instantiating it make it `protected`

Comment: You can only call a super constructor from another constructor..not from a random method..It does not work that way

Comment: Maybe the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is something which fits your needs?

Comment: @BrianAgnew What I meant was more "add functionality to a set of classes without affecting their pre-existing functionality".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've seen commonly is a pattern like this:

```
public class A{
    A(int a){
        ...
    }
}

abstract class B extends A{
    B(int a) {// "proxy" constructor"
        super(a);
    }
}

public class C extends B{
    C(int a) {
         super(a);
    }

    void myMethod(int a){
        // super(a); <- note this is invalid code, you can only call this from the constructor
        new C(0); // <-- this is valid
    }
}
```

Granted, it's a bit verbose and boilerplate-y, but it allows you to avoid duplicating any functionality

Comment: You absolutely need a proxy constructor? This is a pain if you have many :(.

Comment: @Nepoxx Although not my answer - yes, you need it. The only thing you can do is make all constructors no-argument, then you do not need to declare any of it at all (if they do nothing, of course).

Comment: Yes, you need it when adding a class-in-the-middle and needing access to the superclass constructor. There are other options such as a factory though, depending on the specifics of your problem

Comment: This creates a C which is immediately available for garbage collection?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Yes, it was intended merely as a demonstration :)

Answer (score 6):

You will not be able to declare class `B` like you wrote. To create an instance of `B` you'll need to call `A` constructor:

```
public abstract class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super(10); //or other number
    }
}

public class C extends B {
    public C(int a) {
        super();
    }
}
```

In other words, you always call constructor of "previous level", whether the class is abstract or not.

In order to avoid this strange number `10` I wrote and missing `int` parameter of `C` constructor, I suggest adding to child class constructor **at least** all parameters parent class constructor requires for any `extends` pair of classes.